# Delete folder contents within a batch script, windows, without prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script where I have to delete a folder's content, without deleting the folder itself.
I tried using

```
del "."
```

But it stops batch script at that point to ask me if I am sure about the deletion.
I don't want any prompt. Is there an easier way to do this quietly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`del /q "."`

/q: Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildcard

As with most commands, you can use `del /?` to see such options.